# Dapper Class property names with return Datatypes C#

Tags: c#, dapper

I am trying creating the service with a parameter which will connect to the Oracle Db execute the complex query and should return the result in a JSON format. I was checking that the Dapper ORM which would help with this. As the query is complex

```
 SELECT 
 SICD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.DESCR, 
 STRS_SESSION3.SESSION_NUM, 
 Trunc(STRS_SESSION.START_DATE),
 STRS_SESSION3.START_DATE,
 STCD_ACT_DESCR4.DESCR AS DOSE_ACTIVITY, 
 decode(( decode(sign(( DECODE(SIGN(( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) )),-1,( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) ),( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) )+( STPR_OPTIONS.VALUEN )) )),-1,'Y',0,'N','N') ), 'N', Decode (( STPR_OPTIONS.VALUEN ), '1', trunc((( DECODE(SIGN(( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) )),-1,( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) ),( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) )+( STPR_OPTIONS.VALUEN )) )-1) /7)+1, '0', trunc(( DECODE(SIGN(( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) )),-1,( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) ),( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) )+( STPR_OPTIONS.VALUEN )) )/7)), 'Y', (trunc((( DECODE(SIGN(( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) )),-1,( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) ),( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) )+( STPR_OPTIONS.VALUEN )) ) +1)/ 7)-1) , -999) AS RESULT_WEEK
```

[image]

So in the other question I found that the Column names should match the class property also the datatype.

```
public class StudyData
{
 public string DESCR,
 public string SESSION_NUM
}
```

Can the return type be string for all the columns or it needs to be specific return type. Also DateTime will refer to both the Dates(like 18-DEC-12 and 18-DEC-12 07.52.25.977272000 AM -08:00) because I dont see Date Datatype in C#. I am new to C# programming, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: The problem is probably public fields, which are also against best practices... you should make them properties `public string DESCR { get; set; }`.

Comment: If you're only using this query in one place would suggest using the dynamic result and mapping it to the actual DTO...do you have specs you need to follow for the JSON object you're sending?

Comment: konkked, These are the part of the query, The query tat needs to be executed is more complex. There are no specs on the JSON objects, the requirement was just asked if we can get the query response in JSON format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatype of the property should match with the datatype of the column. For example if you have Id column with int datatype, then your property in class must have int datatype.

```
public int Id{ get; set; }
```

C# does have datetime datatype please use datetime as datatype of the columns which are holding date data.

```
public datetime createdDate { get; set; }
```

In your case

```
public class StudyData
    {
        public string DESCR { get; set; }
        public string SESSION_NUM { get; set; }
        public DateTime START_DATE { get; set; }
        public int RESULT_WEEK { get; set; }
    }
```

This could be a possible class blueprint. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Saket, I understand it should be the datatype of the column, the selected columns for example 'Trunc(STRS_SESSION.START_DATE),
 STRS_SESSION.START_DATE' are the two columns which refers to the START_DATE field of DateTime in the  table. One returns the result as 18-DEC-12 and other as 18-DEC-12 07.52.25.977272000 AM -08:00 so do I give the both the columnsa s DateTime?

Comment: @trx Yes, for both column use datetime as datatype. Please mark answered so it wont appear as unanswered.